# Cannot capture the warning message: NoAlertException

Tags: selenium

When I try to capture "warning message", the `NoAlertException` is being thrown. For example I enter a user name and wrong password and click on "submit" button; now a message will be displayed saying "*Please enter a correct password*". I am trying to get this message but I could not find the right code. Can any one help me to get the message?

Comment: Hi user12701 - are you sure that your web page is using a javascript alert to display the message? It might be an html overlay, which you need to look for in a quite different way.

Answer (score 2):

If it is a browser pop-up, you'll need to [switchTo()](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#moving-between-windows-and-frames) that window. Otherwise (modal/light-box) you shouldn't have an issue finding it in the DOM using DevTools' element highlighter.